# using update statement in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update my database using php however my update clause is not working.

This is the code:

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
         date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
        $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $sqlUpdate = " UPDATE booking
                            SET  checkedin = '1', checkin_datetime = '$date'

                                WHERE id = '$flightID'";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sqlUpdate) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sqlUpdate - Error: ".mysqli_error($dbConn), E_USER_ERROR);
     }


      ?>
```

In my database the flightID is an auto increment integer and the checkin is a tiny int.

I believe that it could be treating my variable as a string and not a integer which is why it is not updating in my database.

I have tried creating a variable to to hold the value of 1 and replace it with the hard coded value in the SQL which did not change anything.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it?

[here is a photo for my booking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x2b4.png) 
please note in my sql the 'flightID' variable is actually referring to the id column in the booking table

Comment: Try removing the quotes around `1`...

Comment: @Nick still did not work

Comment: So what is the actual error message you are seeing?

Comment: Also remove quotes from `flightID`

Comment: An easy way to debug is to create a `raw` sql query with data which will comply with your needs. After that make a bindings.

Comment: i am not getting any error messages even once i debug it which is why i am confused, I have echoed out the each value and it is returning the correct result 

i also removed the quotes from flightID and it did not change anything

Comment: Try to change your line with `$result3 = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sqlUpdate) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sqlUpdate - Error: ".mysqli_error($dbConn), E_USER_ERROR);` to `if(!mysqli_query($dbConn, $sqlUpdate)) echo "Query Failed! SQL: $sqlUpdate - Error: ".mysqli_error($dbConn);`

Comment: Also will be good to see your `booking` table map

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco updated my post with a link

Comment: Just check if the value of flight_id, you are passing is there in your database table. And also flightID and id both the columns are same or different?

Comment: @NaveenArora yes it is the correct value, value 23, in my database the id an flightID are different values, FlightID is a foreign key to another table

Comment: Have you tried executing the same query directly  in your database?

Comment: @NaveenArora i dont have access to the database itself as its run of my uni server that i have to be an admin for

Comment: @willzz100 `in my database the id an flightID are different values` can you explain?

Comment: ID refers to the booking ID number whereas FlightID refers to another table where the flightID refers to the plane

Comment: i figured it out guys
when i move the sql outside of the isset($_POST['submit'] it works correctly